# HTML button changes display when I add a background color?

Tags: html, button, background-color, display

When I try and change the background color of an HTML button it also changes the display back to default?

```
<button button="" id="StopRec" style="display: inline-block;"  onclick="someFunction(); someOtherFunction()" type="button">Continue</button>
```

But when I try and add a background color it ignores the "display: inline-block" and reverts to normal.

```
<button button="" id="StopRec" style="display: inline-block;background-color:#2D4A5A;"  onclick="someFunction(); someOtherFunction()" type="button">Continue</button>
```

For some reason am I not allowed to use the two together?

Comment: What do you mean 'reverts back to normal' ? https://jsfiddle.net/jyz22j2x/

Comment: The border and shape of the button reverts to the default rectangle. Vice staying as an inline-block.

Comment: Do you see what I mean about the 'shape' of the button?

Comment: No, I don't... what browser are you using? For me in Chrome (Windows)  the buttons appear quite similar.

Comment: I was able to fix it,`button id="StopRec" onclick="pleaseWait(); stopRec(); hideStopRec();" style="background-color:#15364b; border:#15364b; border-radius:4px; color:white; padding:10px 15px; font-size:15px; font-weight:400; line-height:1.4" type="button">Continue</button>`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the padding, border radius and line-height:

```
button id="StopRec" onclick="pleaseWait(); stopRec(); hideStopRec();"
style="background-color:#15364b; border:#15364b; border-radius:4px;
color:white; padding:10px 15px; font-size:15px; font-weight:400; line-
height:1.4" type="button">Continue</button>
```